# Mapbox.js not rendering properly in React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, leaflet, mapbox

I've recently removed pauloborges:mapbox atmosphere package from my project and I'm trying to replace it with mapbox.js from npm. Instead of the map, I get a random mashup of tiles that gets out of bounds the moment I move the map or zoom in. You can see it on the screenshot below:

[image: mapbox.js not rendering properly]

I get the same behaviour if I try to use react-leaflet package. The only thing I've found on the subject is [this thread](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/issues/951) but people there suggest it should be working fine. I don't really know what I'm missing, hope you can help or suggest an alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing leaflet css (not necessary when using pauloborges:mapbox package). Adding the following to my head solved the issue:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
```